# How to fill message box on Whatsapp Web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send a message on Whatsapp Web (https://web.whatsapp.com/) only using Javascript, for study purposes.

Here is the DIV that has the message box :

[image]

```
<div class="fd365im1 to2l77zo bbv8nyr4 mwp4sxku gfz4du6o ag5g9lrv" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" title="Type a message" data-tab="10" data-lexical-editor="true" style="user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;"><p class="selectable-text copyable-text"><br></p></div>
```

And here is my code :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fd365im1 to2l77zo bbv8nyr4 mwp4sxku gfz4du6o ag5g9lrv')[0].innerText = 'My message content';
```

The code runs without errors, but the message field is not filled, nothing happens on the interface. This code used to run before, but not anymore.

What am i missing ? You can try your self accessing the whatsapp web and using Chrome devtools.

Comment: Since the app is not using an input element or textbox, they're probably listening to an event of some kind. Consider using the dev tools in your browser to figure out what they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

update*

```
// wait until paste all text
function waitForPastedData(elem, old) {
  if (elem.childNodes && elem.childNodes.length == old) {
    return true
  }
  else {
      old = elem.childNodes.length
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       resolve(waitForPastedData(elem, old));
     }, 2000);
   });
  }
}
async function send_text(text) {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.setData('text', text);
    const event = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
          clipboardData: dataTransfer,
          bubbles: true
        });
    let el = document.querySelector('#main .copyable-area [contenteditable="true"][role="textbox"]')
    el.focus()
// select old text and replace with new
    document.execCommand("selectall");
    el.dispatchEvent(event)
    return await waitForPastedData(el, 0)
}
await send_text('yourtext')
```

Comment: This worked but problem is, if the field has already some text, it will add my text to the existent text; how could make sure only the text i send will be filled ?

Comment: check now update

Comment: This works like a charm, even though I do not know how